# Incorrect code generation from room @Query when using Flowable/Observable

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-room

When trying to use RxJava with room, I am getting an error that the generated code is wrong. When returning a Single, it works fine. But when using flowable or observable its adding an extra boolean param to the generated method causing an error.

query

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM cards")
fun cardsStream(): Observable<List<Card>>
```

error

```
error: no suitable method found for createObservable(RoomDatabase,boolean,String[],<anonymous Callable<List<Card>>>)
```

the generated method. If I remove the `false` then it compiles. But obviously I cannot do that as this is generated code.

```
return RxRoom.createObservable(__db, false, new String[]{"cards"}, new Callable<List<Card>>() {
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Replacing

```
implementation 'androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.0.0'
```

with

```
 implementation 'androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.2.2'
```

fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same error but the problem in my case was that I was importing `room` libraries from AndroidX and the `room-rxjava` from the older appcompat type library. ‍♂️